# Getting horizontal dotted screen when booting windows installer via USB

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, usb, windows-installation

I'm trying to boot a Windows 10 installer on my laptop (Asus K53).

The problem is when I boot I will get a weird colored dotted screen. I don't understand it! here is a picture of it:[image]

I tried two USBs, one USB3 and the other USB2. Both of them will result in this problem. And I've checked the USB boots on other computers so I know they are OK.

Comment: What happened that made it necessary to reinstall Windows?

Comment: I replaced my original hard with a new ssd one, and i want to setup a windows on ssd but during booting flash i see that error.

Comment: Does the original hard disk still boot and work?

Comment: yes. the original hard disk still works

Comment: How did you create the boot media?